# jQuery if width is equal to percentage

Tags: jquery

I know in pixels you can do this sort of thing but with percentages, nothing is being returned. How would I go about this if my CSS is using percentages? I basically need to look at the div having a specific value and then firing off a variant of my script.

jQuery:

```
if ($(".modPopUp").css("width") == "32%" ){
    console.log("32%");
    $(".modPopUp:nth-child(3n-2)").css('margin-left', '0');
}
else if ($(".modPopUp").css("width") == "49%" ){
    console.log("49%");
    $(".modPopUp:nth-child(2n)").css('margin-left', '0');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the width that way will always return it in pixels, no matter how you set it, because it is the [computed value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/computed_value). The same goes for `.width()`. You'd need to work out the width against that of it's parent.

Something like the following would do:

```
Math.floor(($el.width()/$el.parent().width())*100)+"%"
```

You could even put that in your own plugin:

```
$.fn.widthPerc = function(){
    var parent = this.parent();
    return ~~((this.width()/parent.width())*100)+"%";
}
```

To be called like:

```
if ($(".modPopUp").widthPerc() == "32%" ){
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LR7Bg/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to calculate before your conditions the percent of your element in px.

Something like that :

```
var width = $('.modPopUp').width();
var parentWidth = $(document).offsetParent().width(); //Document or the element you want
var percent = 100*width/parentWidth;
```

And after :

```
if ($(".modPopUp").css("width") == percent ){
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a single div (or you do care for one of the divs) you can do the following:
Select the element using jQuery, then get the HTML element from the selector, which is the first element in the selector. Then you can use the style property of the element to get the element's CSS.

Ex:

```
    if ($('.modPopUp')[0].style.width == "25%")
    {
       //Statements
    }
```