# jQuery Click function working in Firefox but not Chrome/Safari

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome, cross-browser

I have a button that adjusts a div's margin. I have a function that converts a progress bar's width into a percentage. Then based on that bar percentage when next or previous buttons is clicked the appropriate margin is applied.

This is working fine in Firefox with no errors being thrown however in Safari and Chrome it's not workign at all other than recognising the click has been made. The progress bar won't move so It seems like an issue with the widthPerc function as it's not getting past the condition. I didn't write the function (can be found here - [jQuery if width is equal to percentage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23432162/jquery-if-width-is-equal-to-percentage))

My own click is function as follows -

```
$.fn.widthPerc = function() {
    var parent = this.parent();
    return ~~((this.width() / parent.width()) * 100) + '%';
};
$('.next-q').not('.two-questions .next-q').click(function() {
    var container = $(this).parents().eq(2);
    var questions = container.find('.questions');
    var progress = container.find('.form-progress .bar');
    var prev = container.find('.prev-q');
    var prevone = container.find('.question-steps.questions-one .prev-q');
    var prevs = container.find('.prev-s');
    var complete = container.find('.complete-q, .next-s');
    if (progress.widthPerc() === '66.66%') {
        progress.animate({
            width: '-=33.33%',
        }, 400);
        questions.css({
            'margin-left': '-100%'
        });
        prevs.fadeOut('400', function() {
            prev.fadeIn('400');
        });
        prevone.fadeIn('400');
    } else if (progress.widthPerc() === '33.33%') {
        progress.animate({
            width: '-=33.33%',
        }, 400);
        questions.css({
            'margin-left': '-200%'
        });
        $(this).fadeOut('400', function() {
            complete.fadeIn('400');
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Okay, Solved the issue. Chrome and Safari were rounding the value to 66% or 33% and removing the decimals. Changed condition to `progress.widthPerc() >= '66%''`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely that your `widthPerc` function is returning a floating point number with more precision than two decimal places, so perhaps something like `66.666667%`. When doing comparisons of width percentages, try using actual numbers instead of strings, and try rounding the numbers to account for slight discrepancies in precision. For example:

```
$.fn.widthPerc = function() {
    var parent = this.parent();
    return Math.round10(this.width() / parent.width() * 100, -2);
};
```

Then do the following comparison:

```
if (progress.widthPerc() >= 33.33) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue. Chrome and Safari were rounding the value to 66% or 33% and removing the decimals. Changed condition to `progress.widthPerc() >= '66%'`